# How to enable the hdmi sound on a ECS GT240?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, sound

I can't enable the sound os HDMI in Maverick with a ECS GT240. Why this not work "out of the box"?

Answer (score 5):

Open the Sound dropdown (from the panel), select **Sound Preferences...**, click the **Output** tab, and select the radio button next to the HDMI Audio out device you require audio out on.

*However if your HDMI device is not listed then the device is not properly installed or acknowledged by the sound server.*

Comment: And, in many cases, the latter means you have to upgrade to the latest version of the ALSA drivers (involves doing your own kernel module compilation).

Comment: Don't work. I've try all sugestions in ubuntu forum and until now no sound in the TV speaker.

Comment: When I open sound preferences and go to the output tab, I only get "Analog stereo internal audio". I've started a 100 reputation bounty for a quick howto to make the device (video card? sound card?) appear in the list. The video card is an Nvidia GeForce 8600M GS, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

first check if there is any HDMI device listed after using:

```
aplay -l
```

if there is anything with "HDMI" select Sound Preferences -> the Hardware and from the list below you must select something like "Digital Stereo HDMI output" and it should work.

If that didn't help and you have nvidia GPU then this should help you : http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=69479

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I followed the instructions in that forum but adding 'alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-codec-nvhdmi' at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf didn't make my nvidia card appear when I launch 'aplay -l', or on the sound preferences, and the sound still comes out through the laptop's speakers.

Comment: By the way, there seems to be a "digital stereo duplex" item in the sound preferences (http://i.imgur.com/XoP63.png) but choosing that results in no sound, as opposed to hdmi out. Not sure if those could be related.